# Removing featured image from gallery?

Tags: images, gallery

I'm having trouble removing the featured image from gallery.

[image]

I removed all kinds of stuff from those 2 files, but seems like I need to add something, not take away.
Here are the pastebin's of 2 files:

http://pastebin.com/sBaVzk8y

http://pastebin.com/Ae8TkbAP

Comment: I think this question has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337999/wordpress-exclude-the-post-thumbnail-from-gallery-shortcode?s=2f43d758-b828-448a-8aa4-0423cc5f6342

Comment: I've tried those. I included them  in multiple places, but failed :S But thanks for reference! And thanks to s_ha_dum for converting link to image, nice!

Comment: Another approach would be using the `shortcode_atts_gallery` filter introduced in WP 3.6. It allows to change all attributes – and therefore the passed IDs – without much hassle. See: http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/wordpress-36-shortcode-attribute-filter/ and https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L332

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand how it would work. There's no [gallery] shortcode used in the theme I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the standard functionality of the gallery:

```
[gallery ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"]
```

You can extract the id of the images without having to do a query for attachments of that post
with:

```
preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', get_the_content(), $ids);
```

Then make an array of these values:

```
$ids = explode( ',' $ids[1] );
```

Eventually check if the id of the featured image exists and get its position( i think that it doesn't exists till you don't place it inside the gallery ):

```
$pos = array_search( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID ), $ids);
```

unset that value:

```
unset($ids[$pos]);
```

now you have all the attachments ids, less the one of featured image stored in $ids array.

**UPDATE**

```
<?php

    //// GETS OUR IMAGES
    $query_images_args = array(

       'post_type' => 'attachment',
       'post_mime_type' =>'image',
       'post_status' => 'inherit',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
       'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
       'orderby' => 'menu_order',
       'order' => 'ASC',

    );

    $images = get_posts( $query_images_args );

    ?>

    <div class="sidebar-item not-in-responsive">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                jQuery('#property-gallery-thumbs').propertyGallery();

            });

        </script>

    <ul id="property-gallery-thumbs">

    <?php

        $i = 1;     
        /// IF WE HAVE MORE THAN JUST ONE IMAGE
        if( $images ) : foreach( $images as $image ) : setup_postdata( $image ); ++$i;

    ?>

            <li class="thumb<?php if($i==1) { echo ' current'; } ?><?php if($i%3 == 0) { echo ' last'; } ?>">

                <span class="hidden full"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID ); ?></span>
                <span class="hidden main"><?php echo ddTimthumb(wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID ), 680, 450); ?></span>
                <span class="thumb"><img src="<?php echo ddTimthumb(wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID ), 76, 76); ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></span>

            </li>

        <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </ul>
    <!-- /#property-gallery-thumbs/ -->

</div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment! Sadly, this didn't work :/

Comment: sorry, i'm updating the answer. i hope new solution works

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time mang, didn't manage to get it to work, got : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ids' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in /    error. But there's [gallery] nowhere in my theme's code, so I'm not sure if the whole thing you just wasted so much time on applies. Sorry again, upvoted your comment.

Comment: can you update your gallery template paste on pastebin or make a new one?

Comment: This last update returns in: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_resetpostdata() on line 51. Error goes away when I remove wp_resetpostdata.
It now hides the thumbnail, but the big image is still there.

Comment: The big image is featured image for sure, because it isn't "uploaded into post" image.

Comment: Now it removed the error, but featured image is still seen. The other file has this line: `<?php

 //// DISPLAY OUR FEATURED IMAGE AT
 $featured_image = getFeaturedImage(get_the_ID());

?>`
Maybe this has something to do with removing the feat. image?  However, I cannot simply remove it- this would happen http://www.upload.ee/image/3494306/Untitled-1.png

Comment: Maybe I could just somehow hide the first image in the gallery? Should work, since featured image always comes first.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay but I've been a bit busy, so instead of the featured image, you should place one of those that appear in the thumbnails, right?

Comment: Yes sir! Exactly so.

Comment: I could not find other solutions but to call twice get_posts. The first in the file "with the featured image" and the second, in the other file. Look this: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UXz3M0UE)

Comment: That returns in error: Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array in /data02/virt40025/domeenid/www.objekt.ee/htdocs/wp-content/themes/rentbuy/includes/properties/single-gallery.php on line 25. Such a bugger eh :)

Comment: my fault, sorry! :) I corrected the answer, I used $args instead of $query_images_args, I hope I have solved your problem! : )

Comment: I will not forget this. How can I repay you for your troubles?